# SQL Warning Data might be lost converting column 'S4' from 'nvarchar(255)'

Tags: sql-server

I am getting following Warning message while convert the data nvarchar to float?

> 'Table2014' table
>   - Warning: Data might be lost converting column 'S4' from 'nvarchar(255)'.
>   - Saving Definition Changes to tables with large amounts of data could take a considerable amount of time. While changes are being saved,
>   table data will not be accessible.

What does this mean, will it delete some data from the column?

Comment: nvarchar to float? definitely need conversion which can loose data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the current column is nvarchar it is most likely current records (strings) do not represent valid float numbers.

Thus when you alter the table datatype those entries will not converted correctly (only valid nvarchar reprasantions of float will converted)

**EDIT :**
It sounds to me kind peculiar to make this kind of datatype alter. (Yes in general you will have data loss).

If you want to be more secure try:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD new_column float

update mytable
set new_column = convert(float, S4)
```

And if satisfied do:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN S4
```

Comment: will it lost the data of particular column?

Answer (score 0):

**To my understanding**, the warning is saying that while the conversion is taking place, if any one using the database tries to update information, it shall not be saved as the data cannot be read/wrote until the conversion completes.

With that said, although I'm not sure of the size of float in this case, if it's smaller/set to be smaller than 255 characters, you may experience truncation of the data, so this would be a good thing to double check.
**Edit:** apomene brought up a good point: if any of the data is not a valid float number, it won't convert and thus be lost.